# how to find the difference of a number and it's earlier numbers in python list only if the earlier number is less than the current number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list

```
my_list = [6, 9, 10, 0, 5]
```

how to write a code to get a list of all the differences of a number from it's earlier number only if it's greater than the earlier number

`my_list[0]` has no earlier number

`my_list[1] = 9` which is greater than `my_list[0]` we can find the difference `9-6 = 3`. now `answer_list=[3]`.

`my_list[2] = 10` which is greater than `my_list[0]`, `my_list[1]` `answer_list = [3, 1, 4]`

`my_list[3] = 0` no previous number is less than`2`. Do nothing

`my_list[4] = 5`. `my_list[3]` is less than `my_list[4]`. `answer_list = [3, 1, 4, 5]`

should `return [3, 1, 4, 5]`

my solution is

```
def ans(my_list):
    new_list = []
    for x in my_list:
        for i in range(my_list.index(x)):
            if x >= my_list[i]:
                diff = x - my_list[i]
                new_list.append(diff)
    return new_list
```

is there a better way to this, the nested loops is bit over kill and time consuming

Comment: The problem with your solution is not that it is necessarily slow, but that the resulting list is of a different length, where you lose possibly important information. Maybe consider leaving zeros in the resulting list? That would also allow you to just subtract two of set list from each other, and subsequently replace the negative numbers (or delete them altogether).

Comment: but we don''t need negative numbers. only subtract if the higher index number id greater than the lower indexes numbers. "but that the resulting list is of a different length" didn't got this part. the resulting list will be different length of input list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops, but you can drop the need to use `index` if you use `enumerate`.

```
my_list = [6, 9, 10, 0, 5]

result = []
for index, value in enumerate(my_list[1:], start=1):
    for previous_value in my_list[:index]:
        difference = value - previous_value
        if difference > 0:
            result.append(difference)

print(result)
```

Bonus: your algorithm has problems if you have duplicate numbers in the orginal list, like `[6, 9, 10, 9, 10, 0, 5]`. This approach takes care of it. Your result: `[3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5]`, correct result: `[3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5]`

---

Less nested, but less readable:

```
result = []
for index, value in enumerate(my_list[1:], start=1):
    result.extend(filter(lambda x: x > 0, (value - previous_value for previous_value in my_list[:index])))
print(result)
```